# Archetype project upgrade

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am working on a maven archetype that developers are using. Currently, when we update a new archetype with a new version, developers have to create a whole new project to incorporate new version. What is best automated tool or method for developers to upgrade the archetype and keep their current project.

Answer (score 0):

Archetypes aren't meant for that. They are meant as starting points. If there is a close connection between you and the developers then you can and should be using a source control system. Otherwise, typically a project started with an archetype will diverge from the original very quickly, and each project will diverge in different directions. In fact, if you think about it, each project will start being different starting with the group and artifact names chosen for each person that uses the archetype.